# ffmpeg encoding plays very fast. Audio.mp4 and Video.mp4 work, but both together don't

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

In both steps 3 and 4 below, the `.mp4` plays normally. However, although I've used what seems to be the same settings in the last step (audio + video), that step does not work. The video plays more than 10 times too fast... also the audio does not play.

The ffmpeg messages for step 5 show that it has included audio.

```
Output #0, mp3, to '/tmp/test.mp4':
    Stream #0.0: Video: libx264, yuv420p, 720x480, q=2-31, 90k tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: libmp3lame, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
```

Subsequently running `ffmpeg -i` shows no trace of the audio, but it does report on the  video... What have I missed, to get it muxed properly?...

```
#!/bin/bash

# 1. create Audio 
wine avs2pipe.exe audio "$src_avs" >"$temp_pcm"

# 2. create Video 
wine avs2yuv.exe "$src_avs" - |
  x264 --stdin y4m --output "$temp_h264" - 2>/dev/null

# 3. This works.  (audio only)
# encode `audio.mp4 
ffmpeg -acodec pcm_s16le -f u16le -ac 2 -ar 48000 -i "$temp_pcm" \
       -acodec libmp3lame -f mp3 -ar 48000 -ab 128k  -y "$audio_mp4"

# 4. This works.  (video only)
# encode `video.mp4 
ffmpeg -i "$temp_h264" \
       -vcodec copy -y "$video_mp4"

# 5. This DOES NOT work!  It plays very fast.
# encode `final.mp4' 
ffmpeg -acodec pcm_s16le  -f u16le  -ac 2 -ar 48000  -i "$temp_pcm" \
       -i "$temp_h264" \
       -acodec libmp3lame -f mp3 -ar 48000 -ab 128k \
       -vcodec copy \
       -y "$final_mp4"
```

Comment: Simplify your question please, I can't really get it. You're trying to unify audio and video to the same video file? did you try to us 'map' to map the streams?

Comment: Steps 3 and 4 are only included only to show that the parameters actually work (ie. they aren't completely unreasonable)... I only need steps 1,2 and 5 to work...  I thought I had simplified my question. My actual situation uses named pipes (fifos) along with `sed` filters and I/O redirections to hide warning messages eminating from `wine`... Re `map`, I have tried some  variations, but nothing I've tried so far has worked... I'll keep poking away at it...

Comment: ran into a similar situation working with ffmpeg, good question +1

Answer (score 2):

It works when I remove `-f mp3` from step 5...
I have no idea why, but it works with no other changes.

Answer (score 0):

‘-f fmt (input/output)’

Force input or output file format. The format is normally auto detected for input files and guessed from file extension for output files, so this option is not needed in most cases.

- [FFMPEG Documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)